# TypeError: obj[key].includes is not a function

Tags: angular6, mdbootstrap, typescript2.7

This is the request (Updated):

```
this._service.getPeople().subscribe((response) => {
 this.people = response;
});
```

This is the method:

```
filterIt(arr: any, searchKey: any) {
        return arr.filter((obj: any) => {
          return Object.keys(obj).some((key) => {
            return obj[key].includes(searchKey);
          });
        });
      }
```

The result that I want is to filter the table rows, but what I get is:

**TypeError: obj[key].includes is not a function**

A must know is that this code works perfectly with an array of objects hardcoded, but when I get the data from the backend using a service (http.get), the service works fine and returns a JSON with the dat but I'm still geting the error. Any help would be appreciated!

I am working with Typescript 2.7.2, Angular 6 and MDBootstrap 6.2.2(Angular).

Comment: just tested, and you code works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ar5mwe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The question was updated, please check it again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the answer by my self, the thing is that I had one of the properties null, that was what rising the error, so I just transformed the method below and it'works like charm! I hope this helps somebody.

```
filterIt(arr: any, searchKey: any) {
    return arr.filter((obj: any) => {
      return Object.keys(obj).some((key) => {
        if (obj[key] !== null) {
          const tempKey = obj[key].toString().toLowerCase();
          const tempSearch = searchKey.toLowerCase();
          return tempKey.includes(tempSearch);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```